# Probability to find a great circle touching at least K points on a sphere, given N randomly drawn points

Tags: probability

N points are randomly drawn with a pen on a sphere. The thickness of the pen is of that size that for a great circle drawn on the sphere the probability that a randomly drawn point touches it is p. What is the probability to be able to draw a great circle on the sphere which touches at least K points?

I need this probability estimation (with N=100, K=10, p=1/100) for a historic discussion about whether it is a coincidence that on the great circle through Giza and Easter Island (thickness 1 degree) there are more than 10 important prehistoric monuments.

Comment: I think a solution does not involve any geometry. The question sounds like geometry but it is pure probability/combinatorics.